# How to get the invoice number and Customer PO using a regex from the below text?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

```
Credit Notes - Original

Invoice Number : 362/867/88540129 Customer PO : 124698753
Invoice Date : 2019-10-17 Reference A : BONNEVILLE POWER 
Sales Order : UTS003832 ADMINISTRATIO
Business Partner : BP0042488 Customer Tax  : 12-9871234
```

Answer (score 1):

For the invoice number you may try:

```
(?<=\bInvoice Number : )\S+
```

And for the customer PO:

```
(?<=\bCustomer PO : )\d+
```

### Demo

These is just an abstract regex solution though.  Most likely, if you were using a programming language, you would take a different approach.